# Android wordwrap in TableLayout

Tags: android, tablelayout, word-wrap

I am trying to make a TableLayout for the Android but I cannot get the wordwrap to work.
What I want is that the data in the third column  will fit in multiple lines. 
But what I get is that the data of the last column will disappear of the screen

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TableLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow1" >

            <TextView android:text="1" />
            <TextView android:text="aaa" />
            <TextView android:text="AAAAA AAAAA AAAAA AAAA AAAAA AAAAA AAAA" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow2" >

            <TextView android:text="2" />
            <TextView android:text="bbb bbbb bb" />
            <TextView android:text="BBBB BBBB BBB BBB BBB BBB BBBB BBBBB BB" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using `android:shrinkColumns="2"` in your **TableLayout**

Comment: To do it programmatically: `myTableLayout.setColumnShrinkable(2, true)`.